# How to make one tab bar in QTabWidget expendable?

Tags: pyqt, customization, qtabwidget

I need to customize my QTabWidget so that one of its tab bars (lets say there are 4 tabs overall) has expanding property and will fill the remaining space between other tabs. Any ideas?

Comment: You want the tabs to look like this?  `/----\/-------------------\/----\ `

Comment: |/'''''''TAB1'''''''\/'''''''TAB2'''''''\/'''''''''''''''''''''''TAB3'''''''''''''''''''''''\/'''''''TAB4'''''''\|
More or less something like this ;) And the width of this 3rd tab is unknown, it must be expanding all the way and move this last tab to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can subclass `QTabBar`, set it to the width of your tabwidget (the height depends on the fontsize) and overwrite `tabSizeHint()`:

```
class tabBar(QTabBar):

    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setFixedSize(width, height)

    def tabSizeHint(self, i):
        f = 3                           # Tab3 shall be f times wider then the other tabs
        tw = int(self.width()/(self.count() + f -1))        # width per Tab
        if i == 2:                      # Tab3                      
            # return QSize(tw*f, self.height())         edited -> rounding error possible
            return QSize(self.width() - (self.count() - 1)*tw, self.height())
        return QSize(tw, self.height())             # all other tabs
```

and set this tabBar to your tabwidget:

```
tb = tabBar(tabWidget.width(), 34)                  # tabBars height depends on fontSize
tabwidget..setTabBar(tb)
```

looks like this:

[image: tabwidget with expanded tab]

**edit:**

if the tabWidget is resized, a `resizeEvent()` occurs. In this moment the tabWidget already has its new size and is repainted immediatedly after the resizeEvent(),
[see QT-Doc QTabWidget.resizeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent)

So if the `width()` of the tabBar is adapted in `resizeEvent()`, the tabBar will always have the same width as the tabwidget. Because the `tabSizeHint()` depends on the width, all tabs will have the correct width too. So You can subclass `QTabWidget()` and overwrite `resizeEvent()` for a dynamical solution:

```
class tabWidget(QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.tabBar().setFixedWidth(self.width())
        QTabWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: Well it kind of worked, but it is not a dynamic solution. I mean it all crushes as far as i start to resize main window ;/ Still appreciate your solution thou!

Answer (score 3):

To do this correctly, it's necessary to work backwards from the existing sizes of the tabs. This is because the tab sizes are affected by the current style, and by other features such as tab close buttons. It's also important to set a minimum size for the tab which is exandable (otherwise it could be resized to nothing).

Here is a simple demo that does all that:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TabBar(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, expanded=-1, parent=None):
        super(TabBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expanded = expanded

    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = super(TabBar, self).tabSizeHint(index)
        if index == self._expanded:
            offset = self.width()
            for index in range(self.count()):
                offset -= super(TabBar, self).tabSizeHint(index).width()
            size.setWidth(max(size.width(), size.width() + offset))
        return size

class TabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, expanded=-1, parent=None):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(expanded, self))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.tabBar().setMinimumWidth(self.width())
        super(TabWidget, self).resizeEvent(event)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.tabs = TabWidget(2, self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        for text in 'One Two Three Four'.split():
            self.tabs.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(self), text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 400, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```